# Asp.net mvc - R IIS deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, r, iis, r.net

My app consumes r.net library. it works fine in the development pc (as always) when i run it from visual studio.
Now when I deploy it in the production server under IIS. It throws

```
Error: Package or namespace load failed for 'RODBC'
```

in my c# code i have

```
engine.Evaluate("library(RODBC)")
```

in the server, in my environment variable for 'Path' I have "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.2.2\bin\x64" . Doesn't help.
I also gave permission (to all) in the library folder- no luck.

When I run the r script in R-Studio in the server, it just works fine. But when i run my web app, it doesn't work.

any help???

Comment: Did you actually install the RODBC package on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this one finally helped me solving it.

1. set R_HOME as "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2",
2. R_PATH as "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\i386" (or x64, depends on 32bit or 64bit process), add them to system PATH and add bit to system PATH
3. restart IIS before you try again (iis reset)

taken from https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/462947
(the last post)